# Python PNL OOP, how to use attribute from another class

Tags: python, oop

I am planning to design a program to track profit and loss of my stock account, then I used Python and hope to solve it in a Object Oriented way.

Code:

```
class PNL(object):
    stock_amount = {}
    def __init__(self,cash,position):
        self.cash = cash
        self.position = position

    def buy(self,Stock,amount):
        pass
    def sell(self,Stock,amount):
        pass
    def stock_amt(self,Stock):
        if Stock().symbol not in stock_amount:
            stock_amount[Stock().symbol] = 0
        else:
            return stock_amount


class Stock():
    def __init__(self,symbol,timestamp,price):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.time = timestamp
        self.price = price

a = PNL(0,0)
APPL = []
APPL.append(Stock('APPL',0,10))
APPL.append(Stock('APPL',1,12))
a.stock_amt('APPL')
for stock in APPL:
    if stock.time == 0:
        print stock.price
```

But this doesn't work fine, anyone has idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to fix the class PNL, when you declare the methods with `Stock`, as its an argument/parameter, you'd better choose another name, or write it in lowercase to make difference with the class `Stock`.

Just think you will give an instance to these methods, no need to write the type, and by the way, no need to instantiate again the class inside the method by doing `Stock().symbol`, you'll give an instance, or directly the attribute symbol if you prefer.

Also,  the stock_amount can be stored as a instance attribute, as below :

```
class PNL(object):

    def __init__(self,cash,position):
        self.cash = cash
        self.position = position
        self.stock_amount = {}

    def buy(self,stock,amount):
        pass
    def sell(self,stock,amount):
        pass
    def stock_amt(self,stock):
        if stock.symbol not in self.stock_amount:
            self.stock_amount[stock.symbol] = 0
        else:
            return self.stock_amount
```

Then when you call your classes, i think you wanted to loop on the list `APPL` you've built (then just call `a.stock_amt(stock_object_created)` :

```
a = PNL(0,0)
APPL = []
APPL.append(Stock('APPL1',0,10))
APPL.append(Stock('APPL2',1,12))

for stock in APPL:
    a.stock_amt(stock)
    if stock.time == 0:
        print stock.price
print a.stock_amount

#>>>10
#>>>{'APPL2': 0, 'APPL1': 0}
```

Comment: Hi PRMoureu, firstly, I really appreciate your typing and help. For this question, PNL.stock_amt is the attribute used to store each stock amount in my portfolio so I would be able to get current total "cash" value. So I would need to call the attribute from the other Class and keep them as a hashmap. In Stock('APPL',0,10), the 0 means the timestamp records price change, so would you have any idea how to implement it?

Comment: @SidiChang you can store this stock amount with a similar syntax as used in `self.stock_amount[stock.symbol] = 0` (replace 0 by stock.price ), and then implement another method in your class PNL, which will sum each stock amount  with a loop on `self.stock_amount.values()`

Comment: Hi, but then the stock price would by dynamic changed and highly based on the time series, any more hint would be appreciated!

Comment: i don't really understand what you need exactly from the classes you have : how the amount is given, what do you want to track.

Comment: I would love to track currently how much "cash" I have: Real Cash + \sum stock_amt * stock_price, would this be more clear to you?

Comment: @SidiChang then why not store the list of APPL in your main class too ? it will be easier to access prices and amounts for each stock

Comment: Cause PNL is a Object and if I store the changing data points in the main class, I would need to call the Object lots of times, and sometimes I need to simulate a new algorithm back so I would need to replay time and keep track of price on previous times.

Comment: its not a big deal to call PNL.APPL each time you need, and easier to sum up all stocks.  In _every_ cases you will need to prevent your simulation from erasing the original prices.